# Python, virtualenv, requires dist-packages to run script

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, virtualenv

Python, virtualenv and linux - noob to all 3.

I have a small python project which uses a downloaded package (PyFPDF) within `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.  All worked fine.

I've read using virtualenv is a better way to go as it keeps projects and project dependent packages separate from each other and the main python system.

So having set up virtualenv I now have:

```
~/python/project/folder
                 |_py script file
                 |_folder with some project related files
                 |_env folder
```

.

```
$ ls env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
                            |_folder 'fpdf' & 'fpdf-1.7.2.egg-info'
                            |_others too but not not relevant here
```

However when I ran script I was getting a message about missing PIL.

I see PIL is actually located in original python setup.
`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`

My env set-up has no dist-packages folder at all - linked or otherwise which i thought was the whole point i.e. the env uses common system wide python packages but allows you to use project specific packages aswell.

I'm further confused as to how my original set up worked since, as stated above, I was running from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` which doesn't have PIL in it.

Clearly I don't understand the subtle differences between:

`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`     (no PIL) and

`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`           (has PIL)

Anyway the long and the short is that to get my project running in env I have created a `shortcut` within `/pythonproject/env/lib/python2.7/` which links to `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`

The script now runs perfectly but I can't help feeling I've hacked it and I am not using virtualenv in the true spirit.

I hope my description is marginally clearer than mud.  As I said I'm a noob on 3 fronts here but I'm giving it a crack.  Hope someone can help.

Edit:  so these are my command lines

```
user@dual-lt ~ $ cd /home/user/Documents/PyProjects/PDFproject

user@dual-lt ~/Documents/PyProjects/PDFproject $ ls env
bin  include  lib  local

user@dual-lt ~/Documents/PyProjects/PDFproject $ source env/bin/activate

(env)user@dual-lt ~/Documents/PyProjects/PDFproject $ which python
/home/user/Documents/PyProjects/PDFproject/env/bin/python

(env)user@dual-lt ~/Documents/PyProjects/PDFproject $ which pip
/home/user/Documents/PyProjects/PDFproject/env/bin/pip

(venv)user@dual-lt ~/Documents/PyProjects/PDFproject $ pip install pil
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pil in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL

Cleaning up...
(venv)user@dual-lt ~/Documents/PyProjects/PDFproject $
```

second edit:

```
Downloading/unpacking pil

You are installing a potentially insecure and unverifiable file. Future versions of pip will default to disallowing insecure files.
Downloading PIL-1.1.7.tar.gz (506kB): 506kB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package pil
WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py

Installing collected packages: pil
Running setup.py install for pil
WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py
building '_imaging' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -IlibImaging -I/home/dan/Documents/PyProjects/PDF-IdCardStatic/venv/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imaging.o
_imaging.c:75:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
#include "Python.h"
                ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
Complete output from command /home/dan/Documents/PyProjects/PDF-IdCardStatic/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/dan/Documents/PyProjects/PDF-IdCardStatic/venv/build/pil/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-GxHMlW-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/dan/Documents/PyProjects/PDF-IdCardStatic/venv/include/site/python2.7:
WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ArgImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageGL.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

running build_ext

building '_imaging' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -IlibImaging -I/home/dan/Documents/PyProjects/PDF-IdCardStatic/venv/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imaging.o

_imaging.c:75:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

#include "Python.h"

                ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/dan/Documents/PyProjects/PDF-IdCardStatic/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/dan/Documents/PyProjects/PDF-IdCardStatic/venv/build/pil/setup.py'

exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-GxHMlW-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/dan/Documents/PyProjects/PDF-IdCardStatic/venv/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/dan/Documents/PyProjects/PDF-IdCardStatic/venv/build/pil

Storing complete log in /home/dan/.pip/pip.log`
```

Comment: Ideally you would activate your virtualenv and then install all your dependencies including `Pil`.

Comment: Thanks, when the PIL error first appeared today i tried running pip install pil from env and I got a message saying already installed but it certainly isn't in my environment.  i will try again now.

Comment: @justinfay please see edit in original question

Comment: Do you still have the symlink to /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/? Pip is probably referencing this when checking what packages are installed. Remove this symlink then try to pip install again.

Comment: @pgorsira.  just tried that, same as earlier today.  output added above.  i'm sorry for not formatting the output.

Comment: ok, so plenty on the internet about those last errors.  i did `sudo-apt install python-dev`, then went back into my env and did `pip install pil`.  i now have a pil folder in my env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ folder.  let's see where that gets me.  although lots of comments saying ditch pil and use pillow instead.  need to look into that.